# Is there a home remedy for a dog with a stomach flu?

Tags: dogs, health, medicines

My dog has had diarrhea for two days. :( Is there anything I can give him to settle his stomach? He's not eating or drinking much. He was hiding all day yesterday and lying around, which is out of character for him, so I think he feels pretty bad. I just put him in his crate since he was making a mess, too. Someone once told me pedialyte can be given to dogs if they get dehydrated, so does anyone know about this too?

Answer (score 6):

So... First, I think you need to call a vet, as soon as possible. Two days is a long time, his health is at risk as a result of fluid losses.  Your dog is lethargic, from your description, so rubbing some honey on his gums can help a bit, but you really are at the "***get to a vet***" stage if this is the case.

Now, diarrhea isn't all that uncommon and is often caused by the dog eating something it shouldn't as opposed to an illness. In those cases, there are some home remedies:

1. Food break. Take the dog off food for up to a day and that can allow the stomach to settle and heal.
2. Keep lots of water around, dehydration is a huge issue with diarrhea. Yes, you can use pedialyte to help with the rehydration, go about 50/50 with the water.
3. Pepto-Bismol or Kaopectate can help, but call a vet for dosage recommendations.

Now, if the dog is showing one or more of these signs it is ***critical*** to get him to a vet:

- Black tar-like or extremely foul stools
- Blood in the stool
- Vomiting
- Pain when defecating
- Fever
- Lethargy or obvious signs of disinterest
- Not eating

Comment: Thanks! He's much better today. He didn't have lethargy. He was very grumpy, mostly because he has long hair...and doesn't really like baths... He wouldn't drink the Pedialyte but maybe he's just picky. I skipped the food today. I think I'll call the vet though anyway. He used to take fish oil for stomach troubles a few years ago.